# How to increase length of search api query text?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Length of Search api query text must be 4096 characters. Are there ways to increase query text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **MaxKeywordQueryTextLength** which can be increased to up to 20 KB (i.e. **20480 characters**).  Increasing this value beyond 20 KB is not supported.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $search = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.displayname -contains "search"}

PS C:\> $search.MaxKeywordQueryTextLength

4096

PS C:\> $search.MaxKeywordQueryTextLength = 8192

PS C:\> $search.MaxKeywordQueryTextLength

8192
```

Comment: I'm getting error: Property "MaxKeywordQueryTextLength" cannot be found"

Comment: I'm getting the same as @tomsmithweb - is this version specific? (I run 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the reference blog given https://blogs2share.blogspot.in/2017/05/sharepoint-search-query-length-error.html

Comment: Instead of giving direct links , you can mention key points and then reference to the links. that will help others when the link may become inactive in future.